php unable to access session variable username
I am trying to use sessions in my CRUD application and I don't want to access any file rather than index.php without logging in. After logging in I go to another page main.php which is what I want, but when I want to go further it redirects back to index.php. P.s(In addBook.php I am just trying to print the username of the user for the moment because I want to deal with the problem. Also index.php has just only 2 buttons so I am not posting the code below).
Thank you in advance!
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="logInForm">
        <form action="logIn.php" method="post">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Library");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                exit();
            }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $hashed_password = $row['password'];

                if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                    header("Location: main.php");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    echo "Wrong password.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Username not found.";
            }

            $stmt->close();
            $con->close();
        } else {
            echo "Username and password cannot be empty.";
        }
    }
}
?>
# logIn.php



<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="index.php">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="main-container">
        <h2 class="welcome">Welcome
            <?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            }

            echo $_SESSION['username'];
            ?>
        </h2>
        <div class="buttons">
            <button id="add" onclick="redirectToAddPage()">Add book</button>
            <button id="view" onclick="redirectToViewPage()">View Books</button>
            <button id=logout onclick="redirectToFirstPage()">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function redirectToAddPage() {
            window.location.href = "addBook.php";
        }

        function redirectToViewPage() {
            window.location.href = "viewBook.php";
        }

        function redirectToFirstPage() {
            <?php
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            ?>
            window.location.href = "index.php";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

# main.php

<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
    <!-- <header>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="main.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="viewBook.php">View Books</a></li>
            <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="index.php">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header> -->
    <div class="book-container">
        <h2>Add your book</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="bookName" />
            <label>Author:</label>
            <input type="text" name="authorName" />
            <label>Price:</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" />
            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <input type="number" name="quantity" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php
    // Check if username is set in the session
    if (isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
        echo "<h2>" . $_SESSION["username"] . "aaa" . "</h2>";
    } else {
        echo "<h2>Username not set</h2>";
    }

    ?>
</body>

</html>



<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST["bookName"]) && isset($_POST["authorName"]) && isset($_POST["price"]) && isset($_POST["quantity"])) {
        $name = $_POST["bookName"];
        $author = $_POST["authorName"];
        $price = $_POST["price"];
        $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];

        // var_dump($name, $author, $price, $quantity);


        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Library");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL" . mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
        }

        if ($price <= 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Price must be a positive number');</script>";
            $_SESSION["negative_price_alert_displayed"] = true;
        } else {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE name = ?";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "Book already exists";
                exit();
            }

            $query = "INSERT INTO Books(name,author,price,quantity) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param("ssdd", $name, $author, $price, $quantity);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo "<script>document.getElementById('bookForm').reset();</script>";
                header("Location: viewBook.php");
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "Failed to insert book";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "All fields must be filled";
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION["negative_price_alert_displayed"]) && $_SESSION["negative_price_alert_displayed"]) {
        unset($_SESSION["negative_price_alert_displayed"]);
    }
}
?>

# addBook.php


Check your error log for "headers already sent" warnings and fix them. This can prevent the session cookie from being set.

You're unconditionally calling unset($_SESSION['username']) on main.php.  You may be misunderstanding the difference between server-side code and client-side code.

Regarding the linked duplicate, refer specifically to your redirectToFirstPage() JavaScript function.  It isn't doing what you think.  The PHP code within that function executes server-side when you load the page.  And since it's not wrapped in any kind of condition, it always executes.  All the JavaScript code does is redirect the user if they click on that link.  But no matter what link you click on, that PHP code already ran before you even saw the link in the first place.

How can I destroy the session then? Because I want to log out when I click that button?

To make the server do something when javascript code is run, the browser must send another http request to the server. It's the same as anytime you want the server to do something.  So when you redirect the user, that request needs to be the one which unsets the session value
